# How to return a string with padded spaces in this method in Java

Tags: java, methods

So I have to create a method to return the amount provided as a string formatted in "accounting format"; that is, a negative amount will have brackets around it and there will be a comma after every three digits to the left of the decimal. Any digits to the right of the decimal will be rounded to 2 decimal places.
If the amount is negative, the returned string will have the right bracket
as its right-most character. If the amount is positive, the return string will 
have a space as its right-most character. The width provided will determine how many characters wide the returned string is. If the width is greater than the minimum number of characters needed to represent the formatted value, the returned string will be left-padded with spaces. If the width is less than or equal to this minimum, then the width will be ignored.

So far my code is:

```
 String amountString = String.format("%,.2f", amt);

    if (amt < 0){
        String positionAmount = amountString.substring(1, amountString.length());
        amountString = '(' + positionAmount + ")";
    }
    else{

    }

    //apply width
    if(amountString.length() < width){
        amountString = amountString + " ";
    }
    return amountString;
}}`
```

My problem with this code is when I input the number "1000" with width of 10, it outputs "1,000.00 " instead of " 1,000.00 " which should have a space at the beginning because the width is 10 and there should be ONLY one space at the end.

What changes should I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: is because you don't put space at the start  (ammountString = " " + amountString + " ")

Comment: But now if I input 0 with width 1 its "0.00 " instead of "0.00"

Comment: take a look at this http://puu.sh/yjfts/2f1b2a6c5a.png

Comment: Ok now i can help you

Comment: yeah sorry, should of did that at the beginning =)

Comment: yeah but is not the good thing if i see you picture that don't work for rigth only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String amountString = String.format("%,.2f", amt);

    if (amt < 0){
        amountString = amountString.substring(1, amountString.length());
        amountString = "(" + amountString + ")";
    }
    else if(amountString.length() < width){
        amountString = amountString + " ";
    }

    while(amountString.length() < width)
    {
        amountString = " " + amountString;
    }

    System.out.println("{" + amountString + "}");
```

Output

```
{      1,000.00 } //amt 1000, width 15

{ 1,000.00 } //amt 1000, width 10

{(1,000.00)} //amt 1000, width 10 not sure about the bracket but this is my guess

{     5.00 } //amt 5, width 10

{                     2,020.57 } //amt 2020.5678, width 30

{0.00} //amt 0, width 1
```

Comment: This kind of solves the problem for 1000 with width 10, but for "0.0" with width 1 now its "0.00 " instead of "0.00". Here is a screenshot of my testing framework http://puu.sh/yjfts/2f1b2a6c5a.png

Comment: i added an else if that should solve that case but note nowhere in your question do you state that as a case. your explanation says that every positive number should have a space as its right most character.

Comment: Wow this does! So I missed that else if statement..Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't add " " before amountString

**Example**

```
//apply right side
if (amountString.length() < width) {
    amountString = amountString + " ";
}

//apply left side
if(amountString.length() < width){
    amountString = " " + amountString;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://puu.sh/yjfts/2f1b2a6c5a.png
Now if I input 0 with width 1 its "0.00 " instead of "0.00"